# Exporting Data from Access into a CSV File for Use in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ms-access, etl

I need to recreate a database in a MongoDB backend environment that's currently in Microsoft Access format. Please note: I am not very familiar with MS Access. When I open up the db in question and click on "External Data" I see options to:

1.) "Import the source data into a new table in the current database" -- I clearly don't want this, and

2.) "Link to the data source by creating a linked table". I don't think I want this either.

I assume what I need is to download a version of this db as a CSV file. From there I can write an ETL to get the data into a mongo collection.

How do I do this from within Access? Is there an option to simply download the data onto my local computer in something like CSV format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I open up the db in question and click on "External Data" I see
>   options to:

You will also se icons with small arrows for *export to Excel or text files* - which, that latter, is what you are after.